# How can I serve an additional directory with static assets via Vite Dev Server?

Tags: vite

In case of Webpack, I can use `contentBase` property, that can be a list of static directories. But in case of Vite, there is only `publicDir`.

What is the easiest way to serve one more directory? I don't need to copy it during `build`, it's needed only for development.